# Timer1 on ATtiny85 not working as expected

Tags: microcontroller, avr, timer, interrupts, attiny

I am trying to use Timer1 on the ATtiny85 (Adafruit Trinket) to blink an LED every second. The prescaler value is 1024, and the compare register value is 28. I loop through this 279 times to get a delay of 1 second.

$$\frac{1024\ . 28\ . 279}{8\ .10^6}\simeq1$$

With the code below I get something like 8.5 seconds. I set -mmcu=attiny85 and -DF_CPU=8000000UL when compiling. What could I be missing.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define TIMER_OVERFLOW_COUNT 279

volatile uint16_t timerCount = TIMER_OVERFLOW_COUNT;
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    timerCount++;
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 1 << DDB1;
    OCR1C = 28;
    TIMSK = 1 << TOIE1;
    sei();
    TCCR1 = (1 << CS13) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);
    while( 1)
    {
        if( timerCount >= TIMER_OVERFLOW_COUNT)
        {
            timerCount = 0;
            PORTB ^= 1 << PORTB1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updating the `timerCount` in both interrupt handler and the loop is a *bad* idea. You have a race condition here. Why not put all of the logic in the handler? It's not that heavy.

Comment: @EugeneSh. while true, I find it hard to believe it happens all the time on a system which has a much higher frequency than the interrupt frequency. Disabling the interrupts before and enabling after the change in the main function is still a good idea... I don't like the arcane magic to set the frequency with a compiler option though - is it really running at 8 MHz? Are there prescalers for peripherals in the ATTiny85?

Comment: Are you sure that the MCU runs on 8 MHz?

Comment: @EugeneSh., thanks. But that does not solve the issue I am having.

Comment: Why is this `F_CPU` is needed at all? I think it is used only for some library delay functions which are not used in the code.

Comment: With the default 1 MHz clock, this delay should be around 8 sec.

Comment: Wait. You don't want to interrupt on overflow, you want to interrupt on compare match

Comment: @BenceKaulics. I had got this to work with timer 0. I am certain that it is 8MHz.

Comment: @EugeneSh got it right you get an interrupt on overflow not when the counter reaches 28. You have to set the `OCIE1C` bit not the `TOIE1` in `TIMSK`. As far as I remember.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You might be right, I think. My problem now is that I am not seeing how to do it.

Comment: @BenceKaulics There is no OCIE1C bit in TIMSK. So it is not possible to have an interrupt on compare match unless I am using OCR1A or OCR1B?

Comment: @SubaThomas I *am* right for sure. But the way to do it should be described in the datasheet an demonstrated in some tutorials around.

Comment: It was just a guess as you are setting `OCR1C = 28` but then use `OCR1A = 28;` and set `OCIE1A`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. In the datasheet there is no TIMER1_COMPC. So while I agree you are right, I don't think it is possible to trigger this compare match interrupt. (Unless I am not looking carefully enough.)

Comment: There is `TIMER1_COMPA`.. you can use it very well too. Or you can still use the overflow interrupt if calculating the initial timer value correctly (MAX-28) each time.

Comment: @EugeneSh and Bence Kaulics, thanks for your help. I read the datasheet with a bit more care and found this: "In the normal mode an overflow interrupt (TOV1) is generated when Timer/Counter1 counts from $FF to $00..." Essentially the compare match option is not available in the normal mode. I changed TIMER_OVERFLOW_COUNT to 31 and set OCR1C to 255 (which is really superfluous) and things work as expected.

Comment: *Essentially the compare match option is not available in the normal mode* Sound really suspicious to me. How have you came to this conclusion?

Comment: 1) When I am in the normal mode, TCNTI is counting 255 times. The delay in my initial code was 9.1 $$\frac{1024\ . 255\ . 279}{8\ .10^6} $$ 2) I could find no compare match interrupt documented. Only the overflow interrupt is documented in this mode.

Comment: I wrote a code for 1 sec interrupt for another avr in this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/12-hours-delay-with-atmega16a/178752#178752) with Output Compare A Match Interrupt. The timer should be in CTC (Clear Timer on Compare match) mode.

Comment: @BenceKaulics, this timer does not have a CTC mode. There is a CTC1 bit that resets the timer counter when there is a match with OCR1C, but no interrupt to capture when it happens.

Comment: @SubaThomas -- _this timer does not have a CTC mode_ I am very late to this thread, but you are absolutely right. Thank you for spotting  that subtle difference -- the datasheet is so confusing in the wording. I got around this by using PWM1A mode and setting both OCR1A and OCR1C to the desired TOP -- in my case 103 on a 1MHz to get 9600 bps. Thanks again. Life-saver comment right here!

Answer (score 1):

The CKDIV8 fuse is programmed on devices fresh from the factory. If you forget to unprogram this fuse then the device will run at 1/8 the expected clock speed.