# AVR: Using ATmega328 Timer1 to create a delay

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, embedded

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around this, and it might just be some small error somewhere, that I keep missing .. but as it stands, I am trying to create a hardware "delay" that can run at the same time some code executes.

For practise purposes, I am simply trying to blink an LED at PD4 at an interval of 1 second.

I have used the following formula to determine the prescaler, and the value of the Output Compare Register A (OCR1A):

[image: Formula for calculation]

Using a prescaler of 256, I get a value for OCR1A of 62499:

[image: Result of calculation]

Looking at the registers TCCR1A and TCCR1B in the datasheet, I set the Waveform Generation Mode bits (WGM) to use CTC and the Clock Select bits to use the 256 prescaler.

Now, in my main function, I am starting of by turning on the LED, then calling my function that should start the timer. I am then checking to see if the overflow flag has been set in TIFR1, and if it has, I am turning of the LED and writing a logic 1 to TOV1 to reset the overflow flag.

```
int main(void) {
   DDRD = 0xFF;
   PORTD = 0x00;

   while (1) {

      // Turn on LED at PD4
      PORTD |= (1 << PD4);

      oneSecondDelay();

      // Checking to see if the overflow flag has been set
      if (TOV1 == 1) {

         // Turn off LED at PD4
         PORTD &= ~(1 << PD4);

         // Set 1 in the Output Compare A Flag to reset the overflow flag
         TIFR1 = (1 << TOV1);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

In my function I start off by setting OCR1A to the value that I calculated earlier.
I then set the bits in the TCCR1B register that needs to be set for using the specific prescaler and CTC mode, and I then create a loop while waiting for the overflow event to happen; which I envision should take one second.

```
void oneSecondDelay() {
   // Set the target value to 62499
   OCR1A = 0xF423;

   // Set prescaler to 256 and start the timer
   TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12);

   // Waiting for the overflow event
   while ((TIFR1 & (1 <<  OCF1A))) {

   }
}
```

**TLDR: Now the problem is that no matter what I can dream up, the LED is just constantly turned on, and I am not sure if I am setting the the wrong values in the registers, or if I am just having some brain farts?**

Comment: You turn OFF the led after one second but then widout any "delay" you turn ON the led again.

Comment: Check this: [12 hours delay with ATmega16A](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/12-hours-delay-with-atmega16a/178752#178752).

Comment: Thank you so much @BenceKaulics ! Using the interrupt what something that I hadn't found, so this was a huge help and I finally thing that I understand it :)

Comment: G36 already gave a hint and I suggest you use an ISR for timer1 (ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)) where you toggle your LED with `PORTD ^= 1 << PD4;`

Comment: I tried doing what G36 talked about, but that didn't do it for me, however using the ISR did the trick.. I simply didn't know about the ISR before @BenceKaulics mentioned it ! :) But thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
void oneSecondDelay() {
```

that function's construct isn't terribly optimal. you could have easily made it take a parameter to determine the length of the delay, not to mention other issues.

A quick fix would be something like this - it still has issues but at least workable.

```
//create a user-specified delay
//dly-duration in timer ticks
//timer1 presummed running, running at 256:1 prescaler
void myDelay(uint16_t dly) {
   // Set the target value to 62499
   OCR1A = TCNT1 + dly - 1;     //0xF423;

   // Set prescaler to 256 and start the timer
   //TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12);
   TCCR1B = (TCCR1B &~0x07) | (TMR1_PS256x & 0x07); //set timer1 prescaler to 256:1

   // Waiting for the overflow event
   while ((TIFR1 & (1 <<  OCF1A)) == 0) {

   }

   TIFR1 |= (1<<OCF1A);         //clear the flag

}
```

that piece of code in action when fed TMR1_PS100ms as a parameter:

[image]

the goal of writing any piece of code is so that you don't have to write it again. That way, anything you write is an investment, not an expense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know that I should use a parameter to specify the length of the duration, but I was just trying to wrap my head around how the whole AVR thing works, so trying to keep it at bare minimum. I managed to solve by using interrupts in the end :) Also, was wondering how you made that nice looking digital analysis at the end? :)