# Programming ATtiny85 for 5 sec delay

Tags: microcontroller, attiny

I am trying to work with attiny85 to give a delay of 5 sec when a signal from IR sensor, before giving it to 8051. I am quite not getting the code work for it as it should. Actually I am programming it in mikroC IDE and not sure about syntax.
Here is the code that I tried:

```
void main()
{
 DDRB = 0b000111;       // set LED at pin B0,B1,B2 as output.
 while(1)
{ if ((PORTB3 & 1) !=0) // check B3 and delay if 1
   {Delay_ms(2000);
   PORTB = 0b000001;
   if ((PORTB4 & 3) !=0) // check B4 and delay if 1 while B3 is 1
   Delay_ms(2000);
   PORTB = 0b000011;
   }
   else
   PORTB = 0b000100;   //else LED at b2 is high
 }
}
```

I tried using arduino ide but then I am not able to simulate it in proteus.
Please help me with this. 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not understanding why there's Delay_ms(2000) in your code yet you want 5 seconds delay which would be achieved using Delay_ms(5000). Is that all your code? Depending on the IR remote and the IR sensor you might need code to detect the codes being sent from the remote. There's a library for that btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [12 hours delay with ATmega16A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178227/12-hours-delay-with-atmega16a)

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the error in my code...In the if statement to read from a pin of attiny, it is supposed to be 'if (PINB & 0b010000)' i.e.reading from pin b4.
Also as @Bimpelrekkie said it for a 5 sec delay it is supposed to be Delay_ms(5000). Anyways thanks for help